# Seeking an example for Bayes estimator of two unknown parameters

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, bayesian, parameter-estimation

I searched the web, taking advantage of several search approaches; however, due to redundancy of the existing information about Bayes estimator of one unknown parameter of random variables (either in single-parameter random variables or supposing the other parameters to be known), I could not find an example which explains, step by step, estimating two unknown parameters of a random variable.

(1) I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77566/bayesian-estimation-with-two-parameters) in which the questioner is seeking for solving such question; but it is just a trial.

(2) I also found some papers about Bayes estimation and prediction of the two-parameter gamma distribution but again I could not find proof of the relation.

Can anyone please cite me a reference in which I can find such example with proof?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what kind of proof and what kind of relation are you looking for? The one-dimensional case is quite intuitively extendable to the multidimensional cases. Could you be more specific on what aspects are bothering your?

Comment: Generalization did not seem straightforward for me, thus far. Your comment forced me to come back to my previously read documents, more deeply and basically. Since the study took time, I wrote this comment as an initial thank and delivery report!

Comment: @Tomas, Thanks! After reviewing my previous studies and ..., I simply extended the one dimensional case. So, having a random variable with two parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, the Bayesian estimation of $p_1$ is simply
\begin{align*}
&\hat{p_1}=E[p_1|x]=\int p_1\frac{f(x|p_1)\pi(p_1)}{f(x)}dp_1=\int p_1\frac{\int f(x|p_1,p_2)dp_2\pi(p_1)}{\int\int f(x|p_1,p_2)dp_2\pi(p_1)dp_1}dp_1
\end{align*}
where $f(x|p_1,p_2)$ is the joint posterior pdf of $p_1$ and $p_2$ and $\pi(p_1)$ is its prior pdf.

Comment: You are basically correct. But few corrections: it is not a Bayesian estimation, but Bayes estimator - the value that you get while taking the expectation. There are many other kinds of estimators, depending of on the loss function. Bayesian estimation is an overall procedure that your data undergoes until the final value of the estimator. In addition, $f(x|p_1,p_2)$ is not a posterior distribution it's your likelihood, posterior is proportional to $f(x|p_1,p_2)\pi(p_1,p_2)$.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks. Regarding the comments, the question and the answer were edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tomas' comment, I went back to my studies and generalized the formula.

Having a random variable with two parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$, the Bayes estimator of $p_1$ (and $p_2$ in a similar manner) is simply
\begin{align*}
&\hat{p_1}=E[p_1|x]=\int p_1\frac{f(x|p_1)\pi(p_1)}{f(x)}dp_1=\int p_1\frac{\int f(x|p_1,p_2)dp_2\pi(p_1)}{\int\int f(x|p_1,p_2)dp_2\pi(p_1)dp_1}dp_1
\end{align*}
where $f(x|p_1,p_2)$ is the joint likelihood of $p_1$ and $p_2$ and $π(p_1)$ is the prior probability distribution function of $p_1$.

Having the above relation, as an example, for Bayes estimator of Negative Binomial distribution the following paper can be suggested

Ganji, M., Eghbali, N., & Azimian, M. (2013). Bayes and Empirical Bayes Estimation of Parameter k in Negative Binomial Distribution. Journal of Hyperstructures, 2(2).